# Django KeyError at /

Tags: python, django

Hello Guys Im trying to make a Login page and I want it to be validated, I'm having hard time fixing it. I don't know what's going on. The problem is whenever I try to login with invalid user or not registered user I want it to throw me and error message. So I did this Now it throwing me a Error of django.

```
KeyError at /

'username'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     3.2.3
Exception Type:     KeyError
Exception Value:    

'username'

Exception Location:     /home/aakash/Documents/Projects/Imp Projects/Atom-Social-Media/users/forms.py, line 32, in clean_password
Python Executable:  /home/aakash/Documents/Projects/Imp Projects/Atom-Social-Media/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.9.5
Python Path:    

['/home/aakash/Documents/Projects/Imp Projects/Atom-Social-Media',
 '/usr/lib/python39.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.9',
 '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/home/aakash/Documents/Projects/Imp '
 'Projects/Atom-Social-Media/lib/python3.9/site-packages']

Server time:    Tue, 01 Jun 2021 07:08:02 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

    /home/aakash/Documents/Projects/Imp Projects/Atom-Social-Media/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 47, in inner

                        response = get_response(request)

         …
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/aakash/Documents/Projects/Imp Projects/Atom-Social-Media/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 181, in _get_response

                        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

         …
    ▶ Local vars
    /home/aakash/Documents/Projects/Imp Projects/Atom-Social-Media/users/views.py, line 11, in register_view

                if form.is_valid():
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.forms import fields
from django.forms.widgets import PasswordInput
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password

User = get_user_model()

unallowed_username = ['fuck', 'fuck123', 'bitch', 'yourdad', 'yourmom','suck']

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username= forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=PasswordInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "login-password form-control",
                "id": "login-password"
            }
        )
    )

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        qs = User.objects.filter(username__iexact = username)
        if not qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Username Not Found")
        return username
        
    def clean_password(self):
        cleaned_data = super(LoginForm, self).clean()
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        password = self.cleaned_data["password"]

        qs = User.objects.filter(username = username)
        if qs:
            user= qs.first()
            if check_password(password,user.password) == False:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Password Incorrect")
        return password
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import RegisterForm, LoginForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate,logout
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

# Create your views here.
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
            password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
            user = authenticate(request, username = username, password = password)
            if user != None:
                login(request, user)
                print("hello")
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, "login.html", context)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
def clean_password(self):
    cleaned_data = super(LoginForm, self).clean() # I don't think you need this line, try to remove it.
```

Answer (score 0):

It says your error is in `clean_username` function (forms.py file). You need to pass 'username' field in the HTTP POST request you are making to Django server.

Also, Replace
this

```
form.cleaned_data["username"]
```

with this

```
form.cleaned_data=("username", None)
```

This will get the `username` key if present else will return `None`. Saves you from KeyErrors.

Answer (score 0):

In your method `clean_password` you write `self.cleaned_data["password"]` but this is not correct as the `password` field may not have been cleaned yet when `clean_password` is called, which is in fact what happens giving you an error. To [Clean and validate fields that depend on each other [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) one should instead override the `clean` method of the form:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username= forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=PasswordInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "login-password form-control",
                "id": "login-password"
            }
        )
    )

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        qs = User.objects.filter(username__iexact = username)
        if not qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Username Not Found")
        return username
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        username = cleaned_data["username"]
        password = cleaned_data["password"]

        qs = User.objects.filter(username = username)
        if qs:
            user= qs.first()
            if check_password(password,user.password) == False:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Password Incorrect")
        return cleaned_data
```